# How can I use "class" as an enum value in Python/SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

I have a model in SQLAlchemy of which one column is an enum. Wanting to stay as close to vanilla SQLAlchemy and the Python3 stdlib as possible, I've defined the enum against the stdlib's `enum.Enum` class, and then fed that to SQLAlchemy using its `sqlalchemy.Enum` class (as recommended somewhere in the SQLAlchemy documentation.)

```
class TaxonRank(enum.Enum):

    domain = "domain"
    kingdom = "kingdom"
    phylum = "phylum"
    class_ = "class"
    order = "order"
    family = "family"
    genus = "genus"
    species = "species"
```

And in the model:

```
rank = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Enum(TaxonRank), name = "rank", nullable = False)
```

This works well, except for forcing me to use `class_` instead of `class` for one of the enum values (naturally to avoid conflict with the Python keyword; it's illegal syntax to attempt to access `TaxonRank.class`.)

I don't really mind using `class_`, but the issue I'm having is that `class_` is the value that ends up getting stored in the database. This, in turn, is causing me issues with my CRUD API, wherein I allow the user to do things like "filter on rank where rank ends with `ss`." Naturally this doesn't match anything because the value actually ends with `ss_`!

For record display I've been putting in some hacky case-by-case translation to always show the user `class` in place of `class_`. Doing something similar with sorting and filtering, however, is more tricky because I do both of those at the SQL level.

So my question: is there a good way around this mild annoyance? I don't really care about accessing `TaxonRank.class_` in my Python, but perhaps there's a way to subclass the stdlib's `enum.Enum` to force the string representation of the `class_` attribute (and thus the value that actually gets stored in the database) to the desired `class`?

Comment: Does using this value cause errors in SQLAlchemy or other library code? You can use `TaxonRank['class']` if it suits you.

Comment: `TaxonRank["class"]` would be fine; the problem is in the definition, specifically, `class_ = "class"`. It's the attribute name (`class_`) not the attribute value (`class`) that gets put into the database.

Comment: Try to use this [form of usage](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#functional-api). If you define `TaxonClass` as `Enum('TaxonClass', ['domain', 'kingdom', 'phylum', 'class'])` you can avoid `class_` attribute name.

Comment: Thank you! This form worked: `Enum('TaxonClass', [("class", "class")])`, to preserve the value of `class` in the database (as opposed to the default auto-incrementing integer.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Sergey Shubin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6682517/sergey-shubin) for pointing out to me an alternative form for defining an enum.Enum.

```
TaxonRank = enum.Enum("TaxonRank", [
    ("domain", "domain"),
    ("kingdom", "kingdom"),
    ("phylum", "phylum"),
    ("class", "class"),
    ("order", "order"),
    ("family", "family"),
    ("genus", "genus"),
    ("species", "species")
])
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on an interface for a Russian and English database.  I am using postgresql, but it will probably work for any brand X enumeration. This is the solution solution:

In mymodel.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM
from .meta import Base
from enum import Enum

class NounVar(Enum):
    abstract = 1
    proper = 2
    concrete = 3
    collective = 4,
    compound = 5

class Nouns(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nouns'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text) 
    runame = Column(Text)
    variety = Column("variety", ENUM(NounVar, name='variety_enum'))
```

And then further in default.py:

```
from .models.mymodel import Nouns

class somecontainer():
    def somecallable():
        page = Nouns(
            name="word", 
            runame="слово",
            variety=NounVar().concrete))
        self.request.dbsession.add(page)
```

I hope it works for you.